# My Observablearray in knockout foreach binding doesn't update?

Tags: knockout.js

```
 <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>

    <ul data-bind="foreach: arrData" >
        <li>  
            <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

The structure is like $data.arrData which arrData is an observablearray. 
I modify the contents like this:

```
arrData().splice(0, 1, ko.toJS(data.selectedData));
```

The $data variable does update but not the observableArray. But if I insert in the array in the beginning then the old value shows, but not the new one.

Comment: can you add a sample fiddle explaining the issue or try arrData.splice(//).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by reading the value of `arrData` using `arrData()` you're falling back to the underlying array. It seems you want to be using the version of `splice` directly on the observable array itself:

```
arrData.splice(0, 1, ko.toJS(data.selectedData));
```

Comment: And what's the solution?

Comment: Uhm... exactly what I posted (remove the parentheses from `arrData()`)

Comment: Alternatively you could achieve the same by doing: `var temp = arrData(); temp.splice(0, 1, ko.toJS(data.selectedData)); arrData(temp);`